# Send email from Hotmail using php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, hotmail

I need to send an email using php. here's my code :

```
                $to= "dear-angel@hotmail.fr";
                $subject = "demande d'intervention";
                $message = "<h1>Demande d'intervention<h1>
                Bonjour,<br>
                il y a une urgence et on souhaite votre intervention docteur <br>";
                $headers = 'From: DRIF <dear-angel@hotmail.fr>' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: dear-angel@hotmail.fr' . "\r\n" .
                    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

this is how I configured php.ini file:

```
[mail function]

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = "smtp.live.com"
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
username="dear-angel@hotmail.fr"
password="blablabla"
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = "dear-angel@hotmail.fr"
```

I get this error message :

```
SMTP server response: 550 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated
```

I tried to connect to my hotmail account but I didn't find any recent activities so I can confirm that it was me.
I heard that I have to use php mailer but I didn't know how to use it

Can you please help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look at the phpmailer documentation at https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/UsefulTutorial

You can download php mailer from the downloads menu on the same page.That has also examples you can refer.

Comment: Please don't point at obsolete sources and documentation. [PHPMailer lives on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "you're doing it wrong". Calling `mail()` directly is almost always a mistake. Constructing and sending emails is really quite difficult to do correctly, so use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do it for you.

The usual problem on Windows is that you don't usually have a local mail server, so the mail function doesn't work at all. Some libraries (PHPMailer included) contain an SMTP client that can send messages directly without needing a local mail server. This is not always a good idea as SMTP is not good for interactive use (e.g. during an HTML page load), but it may be all you can use.

Windows deployment stacks like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/) provide their own mail server.

You will find plenty of examples provided with PHPMailer - just change their settings to work with your configuration. If you get stuck, there are lots of docs, the readme, the help wiki and generated API documentation, plus a ton of questions and answers here on SO (look under the PHPMailer tag).

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail than port no. will be 587 and host will be smtp.live.com

please refer below link for detail : 
http://www.technonutty.com/2013/08/send-email-through-php-webapplication.html

Comment: yes, but should not use php mail in built function instead it will be better to use mailer as given in tutorial

Comment: But you didn't say that, and that article points to a guaranteed-obsolete and incomplete version of PHPMailer hosted on some ridiculous file-sharing site. It also misses some vital information and overall, as a tutorial, it's significantly worse than the docs provided with PHPMailer. If you're going to use PHPMailer, use it properly, directly from the source, not some crummy blog-spam.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now with GMAIL account, here's my code :

```
<?php
require "C:\wamp\www\PHPMailer-master\PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; //465; // or 587
$mail->Username = "eadhun@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "blabla";
$mail->SetFrom("eadhun@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "DEMANDE d'intervention";
$mail->Body = "Bonjour, il y a une urgence et on souhaite votre intervention docteur ";
$mail->AddAddress("eadhun@gmail.com");
  if(!$mail->Send())
    {
     echo "Mailer Error";
    }
    else
     {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
?>
```

Thank you all  for your help :)

Comment: You are missing `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`. Please look at the examples provided with PHPMailer.